# Do invertebrates dream?

Tags: sleep, dreaming, invertebrates

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream#Dreams_in_animals)

> Studies have observed dreaming in mammals such as monkeys, dogs, cats,
>   rats, elephants and shrews. There have also been signs of dreaming in
>   birds and reptiles.

Have there been such signs in any invertebrate species?

Comment: Do they even sleep? http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1646/do-insects-sleep

Comment: Belongs on cognitive science SE